# Clicking overlapping rects in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a simple game with pygame, and I am running into the following general issue.

Suppose we have two sprites, call them `sprite1` and `sprite2`, each with their corresponding `rect` and `image` attributes. These sprites are "clickable", in the sense that when the user clicks on them something should happen. I usually implement this by adding the following into the game loop:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if spritex.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        (whatever clicking on spritex triggers)
```

In my game `sprite1` and `sprite2` can occasionally overlap, and let's suppose that I always want to draw `sprite2` on top of `sprite1`. I understand that I can achieve this by having `screen.blit(sprite1.image, sprite1.rect)` before `screen.blit(sprite2.image, sprite2.rect)`. However, I would like that whenever `sprite1` and `sprite2` are overlapping, and the user clicks on a point that is both above `sprite1.rect` and `sprite2.rect` only the action of `sprite2` should trigger.

In this simple example, I understand that one could do this with

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if sprite2.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
       (whatever clicking on spritex triggers)
    elif sprite1.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
       (whatever clicking on sprite1 triggers)
```

but this solution does not generalize easily to more complicated situations (more sprites, more types of sprites, pygame_gui elements, etc.).

I wonder: is there a more simple and elegant solution to get around problems like these?

Comment: Add the sprites to a list and sort the sprites according to their priority. If you click, then find the first sprite in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of all sprites in order of z-index/how far front they are, starting with closer sprites.

```
sprites = [sprite2, sprite1]
```

Then iterate until you find the first match:

```
def find_clicked(mouse_pos):
    for sprite in sprites:
        if sprite.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            return sprite
```

You still have to process based on the sprite that is clicked. That will still require some sort of `if` tree unless you have a clever implementation, such as a dictionary of function references (which only works if you never recreate the sprite objects!). However, this is much more robust than having a hardcoded `if` tree in the order of sprite position, because you can easily reorder the list and everything will work fine.